# Custom message type errors

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create custom message with Power.msg:

```
# Power
std_msgs/Int64 voltage48
std_msgs/Int64 voltage12
```

Everything is good until i try to set a value to underlying variables, example:

```
 custom_msg::Power power_msgs;
 power_msgs.voltage48 = 0;
 power_msgs.voltage12 = 0;
 power_pub.publish(power_msgs);
```

This doesn't compile due to error:
`error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘custom_msgs::Power_<std::allocator<void> >::_voltage48_type {aka std_msgs::Int64_<std::allocator<void> >}’ and ‘int’)`

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221023/custom-message-type-errors/) by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2015-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try

```
 power_msgs.voltage48.data = 0;
 power_msgs.voltage12.data = 0;
```

see here:

http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int64.html

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2015-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2015-11-16**:
Thanks! Working now